# Upload files along with dynamic input fields in Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm saving multiple records added from dynamic input fields. Now I want to add file to each input field. Currently I'm doing is storing all records in a object array and when adding a file, it is appended to relevant object in array. I'm adding dynamic fields from sub component. I've attached a screenshot of the dynamic adding fields, when click add new, it generates a row.

My code is so far

```
SubCOmponent.vue
<button @click="addNewDocument"
                        class="btn m-btn--pill btn-outline-success m-btn m-btn--custom"
                        type="button">
                    {{ $t("Add New") }}
</button>

 <div v-for="document in documentArray ">
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control m-input"
                        v-model="document.document_description"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input
                            type="file" ref="file"
                            @change="setFile(document.id,$event)"
                            accept=".json/*"
                            v-bind:id="document.id"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <a
                        class="btn btn-outline-danger m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill fd-delete-btn"
                        @click="deleteDocument(document)">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

data() {
            return {
                deleted_record_ids: [],
                documentArray: [],
                row_id:0,

            }
        },

methods:{
 addNewDocument() {

                let self = this;
                self.models.document_description = '',
                    self.models.document_file = '',
                    self.documentArray.push(
                    {
                        id: 'new_' + self.row_id,
                        document_description: self.models.document_description,
                    }
                );
                self.row_id++;
            },
            setFile(id, e) {
                let self = this;
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                    reader.onload = function () {
                        self.documentArray.forEach(function (element) {
                            element.File = reader.result;
                        });
                    };
                    reader.onerror = function (error) {
                        console.log('Error: ', error);
                    };
                self.$emit('document-list', self.documentArray);

            },
deleteDocument(document) {
                let self = this;
                let i = 0;
                this.documentArray.forEach(function (item) {
                    if (item.id == document.id) {
                        self.documentArray.splice(i, 1);
                        self.deleted_record_ids.push({deleted_record_id: document.id});
                    }
                    i++;
                });
                self.$emit('deleted-documents', self.deleted_record_ids);
            },

ParentComponent.vue

submit(){
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('document_details', JSON.stringify(this.document_details));

passing object array looks like

[
  {
    "id": new_0,
    "document_description": "sdvsdv",
    "file_name": null,
    "File":"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJcOkw7zDtsOf......."

},
{...},
{...}...
}
]

in my laravel controller

$file = $document_detail['File'];
            $file = str_replace('data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $file);
            $file = str_replace(' ', '+', $file);
            $fileName = 'file.pdf';
            \File::save(storage_path(). '/public/' . $fileName, base64_decode($file));
```

I'm doing is converting the file into Base64 and pass it as above. What I want do is without converting file to Base64, I want to pass each file in above objects array.

[image]

Comment: Why do you require to not use Base64? Where are you storing those file contents? Be aware that Base64 is smaller for network traffic than byte[] (If using Json format)

Comment: @JonathanLarouche when i'm saving it's give me an error like file_put_contents(/home/madusanka/....../public/{name}.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: The error looks like directory/filesystem access problem. Does your server have write/create rights to the .../pulbic/ path?. Also the error shows {name} in your path, does it misses some replacement?

Comment: yeah i fixed that

Comment: Did it solved also the whole issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the error with updating the controller function as

```
 $file = str_replace('data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $file);
        $base = base64_decode($file);
        $fileName = uniqid().'pdf';
        Storage::disk('documents')->put($fileName, $base);
        return $fileName;

in root->config->filesystems.php
'mason_documents' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/documents'),
        ],
```

and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) APIs to store and submit the file information.

It can be quite a complex thing to set up, depending on your needs. Here is a good guide on setting up Vue with file uploads, it covers a lot of scenarios and mentions how to send the files with other data, too:
https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

Comment: @Turbotails yeah, i read that reference and, it is describing about adding multiple files. not about adding a file along with each dynamic input field.